# main activity background image not shown behind listview

Tags: android

show background image of main_activity behind listview..transparent list view.I have tried to make the backgroung of listview android:background="@color/transparent" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
but no change

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="{relativePackage}.${activityClass}"
android:background="@drawable/ajad" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
     >

</ListView>
```

Comment: post your layout file code please

Comment: Look at the layout of your list items. Do they have a background?

Comment: no there is no background in listitems

Comment: i need background image behind listview

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried to put the background directly to the ListView instead of the RelativeLayout?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="{relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@drawable/ajad" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you try to put the background in other activity, it works?

Comment: Hmm, another thing you can try is to remove the android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
and put the background once again at the RellativeLayout

Comment: its showing in graphical layout but when i execute it doesnt come

Comment: That could be a problem when you load this layout in an activity.
Can you paste your MainActivity code here?

Comment: One more thing to note is that it's not a good idea to set a view's id with ':'
For convention, it would be android:id="@+id/android_list"